# the people who run there so just great people

Tags: pronunciation, listening

I heard [[34:22-34:29] part of this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/H0bA72fjHMQ?t=2062) as follows;

> "You have to be sure to check into the Jack Rabbit Trading Post. Great
> prices and **the people who run there so just great people.**"

Did I hear the part in bold right?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ELL is not a transcription service, and (misheard or not) a single instance on a YouTube clip isn't sufficient to identify a usage that might need to be explained here. And computer-generated subtitles *certainly* aren't worth spending time on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you actually misheard this in this way. The captions on this video are being automatically created by YouTube's algorithm, which means that sometimes you get garbled nonsense like

> and the people run there so just great people

here, even though he's clearly saying

> and the people who run this are just great people
>
> /ændðəpipəlhurʌnðɪs.ærd͡ʒəstsʌtʃgreɪtpipəl/

If you're trying to use YouTube to improve your English listing comprehension, that's a great idea and it's a great tool but you want to be sure that the captions are based on a provided transcript instead of the buggy automatic stuff. If you click the Settings button (the wheel icon to the right of CC), this video says "English (auto-generated)". You want to find something **without** that tag (e.g., [this video about kids meeting a 101 year old](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69HgC2KghBc)).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I hear an /r/ in the word 'this'. So I would say the transcription is not at fault; it's the speaker who is making a slight speech error.

Comment: There's no /r/ in _this_ here or there. You're just hearing him say the word _are_ or _'re_. If there's any problem with the guy's dialect, it's the soft/dialectical vowels he's using but really it's just a bad auto transcription that conflated _this are_ into _there_.

Comment: I listened to it again, and I definitely hear an /r/ _before_ the /s/, as well as after: /ðɪrs.ær/. If you don't hear it, I guess we're just wired differently. Also: what on earth is a soft vowel?